# How can i execute a python function(which takes a parameter) from php?

Tags: php, python, function, parameters, execute

I have a python script which has a python function inside it and function takes a parameter. Now i want to execute the python function. and the parameter is given from php. 
But python file is in another directory.

Ex: php is in `site/ph` directory and python is in `site/pyt` directory

Please guys help me on executing the python from php 
i appreciate your help

Comment: You can use socket communication between them. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965655/communication-between-php-and-python

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing the PHP parameter as a command line argument into Python using PHP's [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Then have Python receive it with its [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) list:

**PHP** Script  *(note: $output is an array and $return_var is a scalar, 0 or otherwise)*:

```
$arg = "argument 1";
exec('python "/site/pyt/Script.py" "'.$arg.'"', $output, $return_var);

// PYTHON OUTPUT
echo "return value is: $return_var" . "\n";

foreach ($output as $line) {
    echo $line."\n";
}
```

**Python** Script  *(note: sys.argv is a list with filename of script as first argument)*

```
import sys

# RECEIVING COMMAND LINE ARG
php_param = sys.argv[1]

def somefunction(p):
    print("PHP Paramter: {}".format(p))

somefunction(php_param)
```

**Output** *(when PHP script is run)*

```
# return value is: 0
# PHP Paramter: argument 1
```