# Calling Php Variables to use it in Python Script

Tags: php, python

So I'm trying to figure out if i can get the variables that i make in Php file and use it in my Python file.

I've read that you can use this.

Php file:

```
$data='12';
$output=shell_exec("python pythonfile.py $data");
echo $output;
```

Python file:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

And if i run the Php it will display `12`

But what i want is to run it in Python, it's like I'll call `$data` in python and manipulate it like make it float number. Is this possible?

Comment: You should call your php script from your python script.

Comment: May i know how to do it? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between PHP and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965655/communication-between-php-and-python)

Answer (score 1):

You should call your PHP script from your Python script, you can use [subprocess](https://pythonspot.com/python-subprocess/) module, and many other ways

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("php /path/to/your/script.php")
```

[Here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-a-PHP-script-communicate-with-a-Python-script-on-the-same-Apache-web-server) have good example, and many others have in Google.

Comment: apparently this doesn't find the file even tho they are in the same directory :O

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Try with `var = ["php", "./path/to/your/script.php"]` and then pas var `subprocess.call(var)`

Answer (score 1):

A common and easy way to share data accross multiple process using different languages is to use sharable system resources. By exemple you could serialize data in a file and read the file from the other process. You can also use networks via sockets but it is more complicated.

Comment: that's sounds complicated already haha but will try to do read and do it. thanks!